# Display Stacked Histogram in Banana

Tags: solr, bigdata, lucidworks, banana

I am using Banana (the open source port of Kibana 3 https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/) to visualize data stored in SOLR.
I have some problems in displaying a stacked histogram. I am not sure if that is possible. To make it simpler, I would like to display the number of events stacked by a status. The equivalent SQL for one bar would be:
SELECT count(EventID), DeliveryStatus FROM ... GROUP BY DeliveryStatus;

There is an option available in the Histogram Settings (for "Mode: values") but it does not display the count. It does something like:
SELECT EventID, DeliveryStatus FROM ... GROUP BY DeliveryStatus;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible but you need to check "Stack" option under "Chart Settings" section in panel configuration (noticed it's unchecked in the screenshot above).

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I agree it is possible to have the stack view but it does not display the count of events, in my case. What does for example SG(8) mean in your case?

Comment: In the histogram above, 8 is the count of SG events, 2 is the count of US events, etc... in the specified time-span. Y axis represents stacked values of "Value Field".

Comment: Thank you again for your reply! I tried you solution. In fact what I would like is to represent on the Y axis the count (in you case 8) and not the value of the "Value Field". Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Welcome! I see your point. I believe this is not possible in the current release but I think it will be added in a future release.